# MouseOver trigger doesn't work in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, mouseover

I am trying to create a `MouseOver` style in the code behind. I have done this succesfully in XAML, but I need to do it in C#. Here is my style code:

```
Style style = new Style();

style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF0000") as Brush));

Trigger mouseOver = new Trigger() {
    Property = IsMouseOverProperty,
    Value = true,
};

mouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FF00") as Brush));
style.Triggers.Add(mouseOver);
```

The `button`s apply the style in the XAML code. I can see them change color when this code is run, but the `MouseOver` never changes. I've looked at dozens of MSDN articles and Stackoverflow posts about this but none of the solutions worked in my case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It works for me!. Do you set these style to button? like nameOfButton.Style = style; Can you post your xaml here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the x:Name of the button is equal to "Button1"

You need to add at the end:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"/>

Style style = new Style();

style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new 
BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF0000") as Brush));

Trigger mouseOver = new Trigger() {
Property = IsMouseOverProperty,
Value = true,
};

mouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new 
BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FF00") as Brush));
style.Triggers.Add(mouseOver);

Button1.Style = style;
```